# How should I create large numbers of lightweight objects whose concrete class is known only at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, clone

The function Foo::process will be called many times. I see advantages and disadvantages to each of these methods, and I may have overlooked another one entirely. Widgets are cheap to create. Foo is hard to template by AbstractWidget objects because such objects are full of run-time parameters, not even the same number of these. (I suppose one could use varargs as a way around this.)

The advantage of the second version is I don't have to require virtual clone or reset methods. A disadvantage of the third method is I don't see how to call it with a temporary object, meaning the caller has to make sure the object doesn't go out of scope. (I can also do version 1 with reset instead of clone.)

```
// version 1, clone the original
class Foo {
  Foo(AbstractWidget* p) : pwidget( p) {}
  AbstractWidget* pwidget_;
  void process(void) {
       AbstractWidget* clean_widget = pwidget->clone();
       /* a lot of code that changes widget state */
       }
 }

// version 2, lambda as ctor
class Foo {
Foo(std::function<AbstractWidget*(void)> w) : widget_maker(w) {}
  std::function<AbstractWidget*(void)> widget_maker;
  void process(void) {
       AbstractWidget* clean_widget = widget_maker(); 
       /* a lot of code that changes widget state */
       }
 }

// version 3, one object with virtual reset
class Foo {
Foo(AbstractWidget& a) : widget(a) {}
  AbstractWidget& widget;
  void process(void) {
       /* a lot of code that changes widget state */
       a.reset();
       }
 }
```

Comment: You should do it in whatever way is best for you in your situation. In all seriousness, though, this is a broad question that depends on what your priorities are (which you haven't stated). "Best" is relative.

Comment: @Cornstalks Mostly time performance. Readability second.

Comment: The first two leak memory.

Comment: @jthill Sure, but that can be fixed at the bottom of process.